# Swipe to dismiss TextView from FrameLayout

Tags: android, textview, ontouchlistener, android-framelayout

I want to dismiss a `TextView` from a `FrameLayout` using the code below.

Currently I am getting logs when the methods fire, which is great!

But how do I perform the swipe to dismiss?

**SwipeDismissTouchListener.java**

```
public class SwipeDismissTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

static final String logTag = "ActivitySwipeDetector";
private Activity activity;
static final int MIN_DISTANCE = 100;
private float downX, upX;

public SwipeDismissTouchListener(GameActivity gameActivity) {
    activity = gameActivity;
}

public void onRightToLeftSwipe() {
    Log.i(logTag, "RightToLeftSwipe!");
    Toast.makeText(activity, "RightToLeftSwipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // activity.doSomething();
}

public void onLeftToRightSwipe() {
    Log.i(logTag, "LeftToRightSwipe!");
    Toast.makeText(activity, "LeftToRightSwipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // activity.doSomething();
}

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            downX = event.getX();
            return true;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            upX = event.getX();

            float deltaX = downX - upX;

            if (Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE) {
                if (deltaX < 0) {
                    this.onLeftToRightSwipe();
                    return true;
                }
                if (deltaX > 0) {
                    this.onRightToLeftSwipe();
                    return true;
                }
            } else {
                Log.i(logTag, "Swipe was only " + Math.abs(deltaX) + " long horizontally, need at least " + MIN_DISTANCE);
                // return false; // We don't consume the event
            }

            return false; // no swipe horizontally and no swipe vertically
        }// case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

**MyActivity.java**

```
 SwipeDismissTouchListener swipeListener = new SwipeDismissTouchListener(this);
 frameLayout.setOnTouchListener(swipeListener);
```

Here are some links, but I'm not sure how to implement them
[Foo](https://github.com/romannurik/Android-SwipeToDismiss/blob/master/src/com/example/android/swipedismiss/MainActivity.java)
[Bar](https://github.com/romannurik/Android-SwipeToDismiss/blob/master/src/com/example/android/swipedismiss/SwipeDismissTouchListener.java)

Answer (score 1):

The [Bar](https://github.com/romannurik/Android-SwipeToDismiss/blob/master/src/com/example/android/swipedismiss/SwipeDismissTouchListener.java) link is a good starting point.

What you typically do is, to set the translateX and alpha property of your TextView ...
Roman Nurik has also added a velocity tracker to detect a "Swipe gesture" and to start a animation that will also animate translateX and alpha properties

After the SwipeDismiss you would do simply call framelayout.removeView(textView)

You may also consider to override the onTouch Method of your FrameLayout (subclass from FrameLayout) like described here:

http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html